# converting list to json format - quick and easy way

Tags: c#, asp.net

Let's say I have an object MyObject that looks like this:

```
public class MyObject
{
  int ObjectID {get;set;}
  string ObjectString {get;set;}
}
```

I have a list of MyObject and I'm looking to convert it in a json string with a stringbuilder. I know how to create a JavascriptConverter and create a json string by passing a list and having the converter build the string but in this particular case I'm looking to avoid the overhead and go straight to a json string with a foreach loop on the list like this:

```
StringBuilder JsonString = new StringBuilder();

foreach(MyObject TheObject in ListOfMyObject)
{

}
```

I've tried to use this method by appending with commas and quotes but it hasn't worked out (yet).

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Note that in a WPF project, you need to add a reference to `System.Web.Extensions` to use `System.Web.Script.Serialization`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18746092/1599699 https://stackoverflow.com/a/19299695/1599699

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I've done something like before using the [JavaScript serialization class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx):

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
```

And:

```
JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();

string output = jss.Serialize(ListOfMyObject);
Response.Write(output);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Comment: Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

Comment: this line before write makes it more readable in firefox and chrome

Answer (score 52):

3 years of experience later, I've come back to this question and would suggest to write it like this:

```
string output = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(ListOfMyObject);
```

One line of code.

Comment: I am so glad to see  answers like this. That year, we were just  confused kids. Years later, things formerly seems so important and hard to us became so easy and inessential, because we grows, however, problems still the same :-)

Answer (score 35):

For me, it worked to use Newtonsoft.Json:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
// ...
var output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ListOfMyObject);
```

Comment: what if you have 2 ListOfMyObject? how would you turn the two lists into, say, a json array of objects

Comment: You could put the two lists into one list, then do the above: ListOfMyObject.AddRange(MyOtherListOfMyObject);

Answer (score 7):

I would avoid rolling your own and use either:

[System.Web.Script.JavascriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)

or

[JSON.net](http://json.codeplex.com/)

Both will do an excellent job :)

Comment: @MatthewT.Baker I don't think that's correct. It's under an MIT license (http://json.codeplex.com/license), so it doesn't cost anything.

Comment: Odd as the [Newtonsoft store](http://www.newtonsoft.com/store) states differently.  Unless I'm miss understanding the licensing terms?

Comment: @MatthewT.Baker That appears to be for [Json.NET Schema](http://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema), which is different to the core [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json).

Answer (score 2):

why reinvent the wheel?  use [microsoft's json serialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) or a 3rd party library such as [json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 2):

I prefer using linq-to-json feature of [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) framework. Here's how you can serialize a list of your objects to json.

```
List<MyObject> list = new List<MyObject>();

Func<MyObject, JObject> objToJson =
    o => new JObject(
            new JProperty("ObjectId", o.ObjectId), 
            new JProperty("ObjectString", o.ObjectString));

string result = new JObject(new JArray(list.Select(objToJson))).ToString();
```

You fully control what will be in the result json string and you clearly see it just looking at the code. Surely, you can get rid of `Func<T1, T2>` declaration and specify this code directly in the `new JArray()` invocation but with this code extracted to `Func<>` it looks much more clearer what is going on and how you actually transform your object to json. You can even store your `Func<>` outside this method in some sort of setup method (i.e. in constructor).

Comment: I agree with this methodology because often the only information needed from a custom object is an ID and a label. However, I would like to point out the code above generates an error. The JObject wrapping the JArray is unnecessary and throws an error of "Can not add Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject."

Answer (score 1):

You could return the value using
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objName);
And send it to the front end

Answer (score 1):

If you are using WebApi, **HttpResponseMessage** is a more elegant way to do it

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, ListOfMyObject);
}
```