# JavaScriptSerializer namespace issue

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio-2010, javascriptserializer

I am having a problem trying to implement the `JavaScriptSerializer` to parse a JSON string received from a server.

I implemented the following code:

```
responseFromServer = readStream.ReadLine();
JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var dict = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(responseFromServer);
var status = dict["notificationType"]; 
Debug.WriteLine(status);
```

I added `using System.Web.Script.Serialization;`

Visual C# 2010 Express is telling me the namespace name `Script` does not exist in the namespace `System.Web`. As a result the `JavaScriptSerializer` is not valid.

What am I missing to use this, or is there a better way to parse the JSON string?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, Jeff. Please note that this is not a forum so the usual forum-style introductions (I'm a newbie etc) plus tags in the title are neither necessary nor desirable here. Have a look at the [faq] and the how to [ask] pages for more information. Also try to get the formatting right in your question.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`JavaScriptSerializer` is situated in `System.Web.Extensions` Assembly. You should add it to your project references.

You can get this information in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)

> Assembly:  System.Web.Extensions (in System.Web.Extensions.dll)

Answer (score 4):

```
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer oSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
var dict = oSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(responseFromServer);
```

This will help you to get the value

Answer (score 4):

Add Reference System.Web.Extensions

then type using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

Now you should get JavaScriptSerializer valid.

You can use better approach by adding Newtonsoft.Json.dll through

Add Reference. See details here : http://json.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem and I added project reference for `System.Web.Extensions` , try adding that reference to your project and see if it helps

Answer (score -3):

install Desharp package you can use this command in package manager console

Install-Package Desharp -Version 1.2.11