# Unity C# POST a string list to REST

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, post

I am trying to POST a string list to REST server but I am having some problems getting it work. I'm getting error `cannot implicitly convert type List<string> to byte[]`.

Here is my Unity C# client script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class MyBehavior : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<string> myList = new List<string>();
    void Start()
    {
        myList.Add("5");
        myList.Add("6");
        StartCoroutine(Upload());
    }

    IEnumerator Upload()
    {
        byte[] myData = myList;
        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("http_//ipaddress:5000/, myDATA);
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Upload complete!");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm running a REST python server that takes a list in post method. Here's the server:

```
from flask import Flask, request jsonify
import requests, json

app = Flask(__name__)
url = "http://0.0.0.0:5000"
list = ["1","2","3","4"]
IPs2 = []

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello"
@app.route('/list/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def get_tasks():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return jsonify(list)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        IPs2 = request.json(IPs)
        for i in IPs2:
            if i not in list
                list.append(i)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port = 5000,debug=True)
```

Comment: What part of the error don't you understand?

Comment: The part about fixing it so it accepts the list in a form that works with my server.

Comment: It looks like your server wants JSON.  Did you try Googling C# Unity JSON?

Comment: Actually i tried but i get the same error when trying to serialize the list with JSON utility

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36244111/3785314) especially the **"MULTIPLE DATA(ARRAY JSON)"** section. Convert the list to array then to json with `JsonHelper.ToJson` then send to server. When posting as json, you have to use set header as `"Content-Type", "application/json"` See *POST request with Json* from the duplicate. I added both links(json and we post request) required to do this in the duplicate link section.

Answer (score 2):

Two things are immediately noticeable: `byte[] myData = myList;` doesn't work (which is what is throwing the error) because `myList` is a `List<string>` type. The compiler doesn't know how to jam a `List<string>` into a `byte[]`.

The second issue is that [`UnityWebRequest.Post`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Post.html) takes a `string` parameter for the second argument (`postData`), not a `byte[]`.

**Edit:** I also noticed a couple syntax issues in the question, but I assumed they were typos. In case they aren't typos:

```
UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("http_//ipaddress:5000/, myDATA);
```

Should be changed to:

```
UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("http://ipaddress:5000/", myData);
```

Comment: they were typos as i removed the original ipaddress. I know what the problem is but i dont know how to solve it, hence asking here. I need to convert string list to JSON and cannot find any tutorials to do this.

Comment: [Here you go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366118/converting-list-to-json-format-quick-and-easy-way).

Comment: The accepted solution does not work inside unity. additionally i dont have anything like "public class MyObject" i just want to POST my list so my python server can read it like list = ["a", "b", "c"]

Comment: @jakkis `public class MyObject` is an example of a class. It's not a library you need to import. Also, how your python server interprets the JSON is up to you. JSON will not be in the form ["a", "b", "c"]

Answer (score 1):

In Unity, set your .Net profile to 4.x .

Then you can use the [JavaScriptSerializer class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) to create the `String` you need to pass to `UnityWebRequest.Post`:

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

// ...

JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string output = jss.Serialize(myList);

UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("http://ipaddress:5000/", output);
yield return www.SendWebRequest();
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6366183/1092820)